# Spotify API responding with error code 403 when requesting top songs of a user

Tags: python, spotify

I've been writing a program to fetch the top songs of a user using Spotify API. The code is mentioned below:

```
def get_token():
    auth_string = CLIENT_ID + ":" + CLIENT_SECRET
    auth_bytes = auth_string.encode("utf-8")
    auth_base64 = str(base64.b64encode(auth_bytes), "utf-8")

    url = "https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token"
    headers = {
        "Authorization" : "Basic " + auth_base64,
        "Content-Type" : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    } 

    data = {"grant_type" : "client_credentials"}
    result = post(url, headers=headers, data=data)
    json_result = json.loads(result.content)
    token = json_result["access_token"]
    return json_result

def get_top_tracks(token):
    query_url = "https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/top/tracks"
    header = {
        "Authorization" : "Bearer " + token
    }
    result = get(query_url, headers=header)
    print(result)

token = get_token()
get_top_tracks(myToken)
```

I'm getting the following error on execution:

`<Response [403]>`

Am I missing something?

Comment: You can't use Client Credentials to request user data. You should implement an Authorization Code flow instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks correct, but you are requesting the wrong type of token for your desired api endpoint. Any user related calls require a user token via a correctly scoped authorization code. https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/tutorials/code-flow